# using boost gregorian in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, boost

using: xcode 4.6.3. and boost 1.53.0

I'm trying to manipulate dates and times using 'boost::gregorian::days'. It's working perfectly fine when I'm building for OSX 10.8. The problem is when I'm trying to build an iOS app. Everything (including other boost functions) is working fine except the 'gregorian' part. I have used tons of different ways to build boost but I still can't seem to manage to get this part to work.

Is there any way to get this to work?

edit: forgot to mention, I've linked `libboost_date_time.a` to the project.

sample:

```
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int day = 5;
    int month = 8;
    int year = 2013;
    boost::gregorian::date inputDate(year, month, day);
    std::string stringDate = to_iso_extended_string(inputDate)

    std::cout << stringDate;

    return 0;
}
```

this gives me the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_string() const", referenced from:
boost::date_time::month_formatter<boost::gregorian::greg_month, boost::date_time::iso_extended_format<char>, char>::format_month(boost::gregorian::greg_month const&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in myFile.o

"boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string() const", referenced from:
boost::date_time::month_formatter<boost::gregorian::greg_month, boost::date_time::iso_extended_format<char>, char>::format_month(boost::gregorian::greg_month const&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in myFile.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```